# iOS-Drawing on an image with CGContextRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontextref

I'm trying to draw on an image using `CGContextRef` with the following piece of code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// After getting the context i pass it to a C++ backend by an appropriate wrapper and do some drawing operations.
```

Then I try to get the image from context with the following piece of code:

```
CGImageRef image = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() CGImage];
```

But this returns an image with size (0,0).

I tried to get the image with:

```
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
```

This returns a blank image with the original size multiplied by 3 for both width and height.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the image is being drawn in the `context`, then `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` should do the trick. There may be some problem with C++ backend.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri Thank you for your response, but I have my C++ backend connected to another frontend and it works as expected.